# Junk characters in Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, dllimport

In below code, pcp_Out is supposed to return system date in ANSI format.

- system date is returned but it has some junk characters in front?
- Is AllocHGlobal right way to initialize *out IntPtr*?

  ```
     [DllImport("Open32env.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = false, EntryPoint = "CallOPLFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      static extern int CallOPLFunction(long pl_Instr, IntPtr pcp_In, out IntPtr pcp_Out, out IntPtr pcp_ErrorMessage);


      static void Main(string[] args)
      {     
          IntPtr OutPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0);
          IntPtr ErrorPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0);
          IntPtr inPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("");

          long invalue = 0;

          int ret = CallOPLFunction(invalue, inPtr, out OutPtr, out ErrorPtr);

          string Outstring = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(OutPtr,30);

          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(OutPtr);
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ErrorPtr);
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inPtr);
      }
  ```

The output

```
Outstring = "h\0Qr\0\0\0\0Ä<g\a?\004/22/13 10:25"
```

Comment: It is *never* correct to call AllocHGlobal and pass 0.  If the pinvoke declaration is correct then you cannot use this function, it causes a memory leak.  Good odds that it isn't correct, remove the *out* from the declaration and create a big enough buffer with, say, Marshal.AllocHGlobal(666).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, better way to allocate memory to empty pointer is:

```
IntPtr OutPtr = new IntPtr();
IntPtr ErrorPtr = new IntPtr();
```

If pcp_Out is Unicode string, then try to use:
`CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`

Comment: Thanks drew, pcp_Out is ANSI format. i have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: If you give me this library, I can try to call the function correctly.